# Overriding Zopim chat widget's CSS to reduce overlap

Tags: css, overriding, magento-1.7

I have integrated the Zopim Chat Widget in my Magento store and it overlaps parts of my content. I want to change the width of the Zopim-Button by overriding the Zopim CSS.

This is what I found:

```
.meshim_widget_components_chatButton_Button {
    min-width: 180px;
    max-width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background: #A0B105;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border: none;
}
```

I tried to override it in my Magentos ui.css by adding

```
.meshim_widget_components_chatButton_Button {
    min-width: 156px !important;
    max-width: 156px !important;
}
```

It didn't work the way I hoped though.

How do I do this right?

Comment: What was the way you hoped it would work? Also, check you're loading your `ui.css` after the original CSS file.

Comment: @Anko: I want the width to be 156px fix. Will now have to find out if the Zopim CSS loads after or prior to my ui.css. Any hints how to check this?

Comment: Your CSS files are loaded in the order they're [`link`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link)ed in your HTML.

Comment: The Zopim script loads last... seems that this might be the first thing I have to change. Thank you, Anko!

Answer (score 0):

Zopim has a [API](https://api.zopim.com/files/meshim/widget/controllers/LiveChatAPI-js.html) that allows you to change the size and position of the chat widget

Answer (score 0):

```
I think this link will help you 

https://api.zopim.com/files/meshim/widget/controllers/liveChatAPI/Window-js.html#$zopim.livechat.window.setSize
```